# VS2008 msi Installer InstallExecuteSequence table

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, windows-installer

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here.  The following questions both reference the InstallExecuteSequence table:

[Force Reboot from Custom Action in Msi in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178327/force-reboot-from-custom-action-in-msi-in-c)

[msi Installer to run twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404288/msi-installer-to-run-twice)

And here's the MS page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369500%28VS.85%29.aspx

There's lots of information about this and using the installer database lying around, but what I can't find is how is the InstallExecuteSequence Table modified?  Or how anything in the installer database is modified?  What actual steps, files, modules or options need to be changed and where are they located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Orca to edit the MSI by hand: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(VS.85).aspx